# Insert or Update if exists not having to use Primary Key

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update my db table by checking if my `product_number` column already exists. I know you can use the `INSERT OR UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY` but the column I am trying to use is not a primary key.

I found the following query on a stack post but I keep getting the error `Unrecognized statement type. (near Duplicate)` when I try run it using phpMyAdmin.

```
DECLARE @numrecords INT
SELECT @numrecords = count(*)
                    FROM users_remark
                    WHERE product_number = '444'
                    IF @numrecords > 0 THEN
                         UPDATE products
                         SET product_name = 'abc',
                             product_description = def,
                             product_detail = '',
                             product_price = '100',
                             product_price_canada = '200'
                             WHERE product_number = '444'
                    ELSE
                        INSERT INTO products (product_number, product_name, product_description, product_price)
                        VALUES (444, abc, def, 100)
                    END IF
```

Why is this query not working?

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Duplicate or Declare? It looks like you're trying to use something like oracle?

Comment: You want `product_number` to be unique, but it is not the primary key of the table.  You have no idea what the primary key is until you get the record via `product_number`?  It sounds like you're going to be fighting uphill unless you can alter the table.  Maybe build an index of product_numbers?  Unless you allow one access to that table ever from anywhere, you have a race condition.

Comment: @NKijak The ideal situation would be to have the product number as primary key but our client changed how they name products so we are still in the process of  modifying the application. Until then I need this to work to update the products table.

Comment: No, the normal is to have `id` as a primary key, and the `product_number` as a separate column, which can have `unique` on it.

Comment: @Farkie why? I don't think there is anything wrong with having product_number as primary key. It might vary based on your needs but if the product number is unique then why not

Comment: @leo_ap that was there originally. Probably got omitted when I posted the question. Doesn't fix the issue though.

Comment: The word Duplicate isn't in your query, so you're missing something.

Comment: @bos570 The problem with using the product number is demonstrated in an earlier comment by from you _"but our client changed how they name products"_. Any time the client makes such changes, changing such a PK could require drastic database restructuring; using a synthetic surrogate key should reduce the changes to within just the table affected.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Your `declare` statements using @-prefixed identifiers, and rampant omission of `;`'s suggest MSSQL, not MySQL. (If it actually is MySQL, it will no way accept such a query... I'm still not familiar enough with MSSQL to rule it out completely for it.)

Comment: @Uueerdo you're right it is MySql, and the query is a MSSQL query. So is there really no way in MySql to check whether to Insert or Update without using PK?

Comment: @bos570 yes, there is, but it seems that you will need a stored procedure

Comment: @leo_ap okay, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @bos570 You should be able use ON DUPLICATE KEY *if* you put a UNIQUE key on `product_number` (it doesn't have to be PRIMARY, just unique); assuming the product_number values are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a procedure for you:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_or_update $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_or_update(pProduct_number INT, pProduct_name VARCHAR(200), pProduct_description VARCHAR(200), pProduct_detail VARCHAR(200), pProduct_price FLOAT(15,2), pProduct_price_canada FLOAT(15,2))
BEGIN

    DECLARE numrecords INT;    
    SELECT count(*) INTO numrecords FROM products WHERE product_number = pProduct_number;
        IF numrecords > 0 THEN
            UPDATE products SET 
                product_name = pProduct_name,
                product_description = pProduct_description,
                product_detail = pProduct_detail,
                product_price = pProduct_price,
                product_price_canada = pProduct_price_canada
            WHERE product_number = pProduct_number;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO products (product_number, product_name, product_description, product_price)
            VALUES (pProduct_number, pProduct_name, pProduct_description, pProduct_price);
        END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

To call just:

```
CALL insert_or_update(444, , 'abc', 'def', '', '100', '444');
```

Comment: just ended up writing a similar procedure and it works. Appreciate the help.